# PHP : Retrieve multiple data from mysql, an esasier way?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a php code about retrieving multiple lines from mysql database **that works very well**. But I find it too heavy. The following is only one extract, as i use the same method for each single word from the database. Do you have better solution? Can I make just one statement for all the page, and just put the requested ID at the correct place? Thank you for any help.

```
  <?php
    $dbname = 'xxxx';
    $dbuser = 'xxxx';
    $dbpass = 'xxxx';
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $conn = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error)
    {
    echo "connection error" ;
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id='1'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    ?>
    <?php
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {                                        
    while($data = $result-   >fetch_assoc())
    {
    echo $data['FR']."<br>";
    }       
    } else {
    echo "---";
                                        }
    ?>

                 </h3><a href="index.html" title="">FR|</a>
                    <a href="index_en.html" title="">EN|</a>
                    <a href="index_es.html" title="">ES|</a>
                    <a href="index_cn.html" title="">CHI</a>
                 </div>

                    <nav role="navigation" class="main-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="active">
    <a href="index.html" title=""><?  php
    $conn = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error)
    {
    echo "connection error" ;
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id='59'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    ?>
    <?php
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) { while($data = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {echo $data['FR']."<br>"; } } else {echo "---"; }?>

    <?php
    $conn = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error)
    {
    echo "Problemes de connexion a la base de données " ;
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id='60'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);    
    ?>
    <?php
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) { while($data = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {echo $data['FR']."<br>"; } } else {echo "---"; }?>    
    <?php
    $conn = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error)
    {
    echo "connection error" ;
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id='61'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);    
    ?>
```

Comment: You can optimize your SQL `SELECT * FROM test WHERE id IN(59, 60, 61)` or even `SELECT * FROM test WHERE id BETWEEN 59 AND 61`

Comment: Why are you repeating creating the database connection?

Comment: You don't have to open a new connection everytime you do a statement. You can reuse the `$conn` variable.

Comment: Try using a bootstrap file where you create `$conn` then reuse it in your sql functions. Those must return `$conn->query($sql))`. There you have an iterator that can be easily used in a `foreach` loop

Comment: Thank you all. Mark and Twinfriends, this is my how to do question, should i just remove the $conn connection line, or there is another thing to do ?

Comment: Raymond, can i do this, even if my values are not following one each other ?

Comment: Alwin...i'll need more skill to do this. Can you recommend a link that explain how to create a boostrap file to create $conn ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure can.

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `id` IN (59, 60, 61)
```

You can fill the `IN` clause with as many id values as you need, and you'll get one row back in your result for each matched ID.

Comment: Thanks frozen, but isn't your solution only valid for values following one each other ? My values either follow one each other, or can be sometimes separated by some html text...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Finally i choose Raymond's method, just customizing the code to my mysql version. I will reuse the code wherever i have data in block. Thanks a lot.

```
enter code here

$sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id IN ('59','60','61')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


?>
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { while($data = $result->fetch_assoc())
{echo $data['FR']. "<br>"; }    } else {echo "---"; }?></a></li>
```